# Passing a number between feature classes in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, zonal-statistics

I am looking at two non-overlapping polygon feature classes (let's call them Counties and Somewhereland; the latter feature class has only one record). I need to sum a certain field (let's call it INCIDENTS) in Counties and populate a certain field (let's call it VISITS) in Somewhereland with this sum. Is it possible to do all of this in ModelBuilder, and if so, what tools would I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use summary statistics with your counties layer

Use Get Field value to grab the sum from the summary table

And Calculate Field to update somewhereland

Comment: Thanks! Believe it or not, I've never used Get Field Value before, hence this question.